# Make a list with a name that is only known after the program runs

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to make a list and call it a name which I only know after I run the program:

For example:

```
#making shelfs
group_number = 1
group_name = 'group' + str(group_number)
print group_name
```

group_name will be: group1

Now I want to make an empty list called group1. How to do such a thing?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? General advice would be: Don't do this.

Comment: Why you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Could you give more details about what you're trying to do (the big picture)? It's possible to do literally what you're asking, but I find it unlikely that this is really what you want.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241133/how-can-i-create-lists-from-a-list-of-strings/

Comment: There was absolutely no way I could avoid this. These shelf groups will be constructed depending on how far the player "has traveled" which is unknown before the program runs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you just put this into a dictionary:

```
d = {group_name:[]}
```

Now you have access to your list via the dictionary.  e.g.:

```
d['group1'].append('Hello World!')
```

---

The alternative is to modify the result of the `globals()` function (which is a dictionary).  This is definitely bad practice and **should be avoided**, but I include it here as it's always nice to know more about the tool you're working with:

```
globals()[group_name] = []
group1.append("Hello World!")
```

Comment: +1. Generally when people want to do this, they would actually be far better off with a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting to create a pseudo-namespace of variables starting with "group". Why not use a dict instead?

```
#making shelfs
groups = {}
group_number = 1
name = str(group_number)
groups[name] = [] # or whatever
print groups[name]
```

This is subtly different to @mgilson's answer because I am trying to encourage you to create new namespaces for each collection of related objects.

Answer (score 1):

you do this:

```
locals()['my_variable_name'] = _whatever_you_wish_
```

or

```
globals()['my_variable_name'] = _whatever_you_wish_
```

or

```
vars()['my_variable_name'] = _whatever_you_wish_
```

Google to find out the differences yourself :P

Comment: Modifying locals only works in the global namespace where `locals` returns `globals`