# making a variable name variable?

Tags: python, django

In django I want to call a queryset but the name of that queryset will vary depending on what variable is being passed to it.

In this example I have a variable called var that will return a value of "fileone", "filetwo" or "filethree"

how do I then use that to create the appropriate queryset to be called?

ie.

```
var = filetwo

queryset = filetwo.objects.all()

var = fileone

queryset = fileone.objects.all()
```

Comment: Use an appropriate data structure such as a ``dict``.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a list with a name that is only known after the program runs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092341/make-a-list-with-a-name-that-is-only-known-after-the-program-runs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach (1), If you can assign Class to variable** In Python you can directly assign a Class to a variable. If your variable holds the class you can directly call it. This is how I do it -

The model -

```
class ErrorLog(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'core'
```

The url config, passing `Model Class` in variable -

```
url(r'^' ..., GenericListView.as_view(..., model=ErrorLog,...), name='manage_error'),
```

Then finally calling the query set in the view -

```
class GenericListView(...):
    model = ....
    def get_queryset(self):
        //other codes
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

You see the query_set will return whatever class mentioned in it.

**Approach (2), if you only has the class name** But in case, your variable only contains `string` name of the `'Class` but not the class directly then you might wanna get the model before calling the queryset -

to get the model class you can do the following -

```
from django.db.models import get_model
model = get_model("string name of model class")
return model.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for!  I've just started building my views as class based to use the mixins for django-rest-framework so this is all making sense now :)