# Create new lists from elements of a list

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to create multiple lists with names from elements of another list.

Eg:

```
names=["Rob","Mark","Steve"]
```

Is there a way to create lists like:

```
Rob=[]
Mark=[]
Steve=[]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one obvious way is like this:

```
>>> names = ["Rob","Mark","Steve"]
>>> lists = {name: [] for name in names}
>>> print lists
{'Steve': [], 'Rob': [], 'Mark': []}
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped.. And its list a list inside a list to add elements to the lists and display them..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [exec](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html) statement with a string as argument.
It will parse the string as a suite of Python statements.

```
names=["Rob","Mark","Steve"]
S = "".join([n +'= [];' for n in names])
exec(S)


In [1]: print Rob, Mark, Steve
[] [] []
```