# Create empty lists with name of attributes of other lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list which, lets say it looks like this:

```
alist = ["apple", "tea", "oranges"]
```

What I want python to do now is take each attribute and create an empty list out of it. So basically this:

```
apple = []
tea = []
oranges = []
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: duplicate. sorry about that!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* (**but shouldn't**) use `exec`:

```
for item in alist:
    exec(item + " = []")
```

This is, however, **generally discouraged**. Use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead:

```
list_dict = {}
for item in alist:
    list_dict[item] = []
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need lists since I have more VALUES which need to go into these created lists (and the dic only has one KEY). However, with your solution `exec`. How would I append something to these created lists? Of course with `.append`, but how (since it does not give me anything as an output)

Comment: These lists now exist. If `alist` contained `"apple"`, then there is a list called `apple` that you can use like any other list (e.g., `apple.append(...)`)

Answer (score 1):

You could do so by holding the list names as the keys of a dictionary. Something like this:

```
alist = ["apple", "tea", "oranges"]
yourListDict = {}
for name in alist:
    yourListDict[name]=list()
```

Output:

```
yourListDict['apple']
=> []
```

An alternative syntax would be:

```
{k: [] for k in alist}
```

as Jon Clements points out in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14241195/2259303

Comment: I support the `dict` recommendation, but that's not valid Python syntax.

Comment: @DSM just realized. updated. thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But I think I need lists since I will `.append` more than one value to the so created list. That would end in trouble with the dic when I try to assign more than one VALUE to the same KEY

Comment: @Christoph the values *are* lists. you could do `yourListDict['apple'].append("myString")`. then if you printed `yourListDict['apple']` you'd get `["myString"]`. It would work just like a list! the only thing different is  how you access it.