# Using variable responses to form new variable

Tags: python, variables

If
    x= Apple
    y = 0123

How can I create a new variable Apple0123 using x & y?

so basically:  COMBINE(x,y) = 5

and if i type in Apple0123 -> the output is 5

Comment: Really, you _don't_ want to do this. Please see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables). Also see [How can I create lists from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241133/how-can-i-create-lists-from-a-list-of-strings).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'Apple'
y = '0123'
x+y
exec("%s = %d" % ((x+y),5))
print(Apple0123)
```

or

```
x = 'Apple'
y = '0123'
x+y
vars()[x+y]
print(Apple0123)
```