# How to append user input to a different list every time a loop runs?

Tags: python, arraylist

```
scores_h1 = []
scores_h2 = []
scores_h3 = []
scores_h4 = []
scores_h5 = []
scores_h6 = []
scores_h7 = []
scores_h8 = []
scores_h9 = []

for i in range(1,10):
   value = int(input("Score: "))
   string = f'scores_h{i}'
   string.append(value)
```

I am trying to append `value` to `scores_h1` the first time the loop runs. And then the second time to `scores_h2` and then the third time to `scores_h3` and so on.. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Use a list of lists or a dictionary instead of 10 variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create lists from a list of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241133/how-can-i-create-lists-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: And [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/1431750)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure this is what you really want, but then the following code does it:

```
length = 9

lst = [[] for i in range(length)]

for i in range(length):
   value = int(input("Score: "))
   lst[i].append(value)

print(lst)
```

Basically you do not want 9 independent lists. You want a nested list. Then you can call each list within the top one with the corresponding index.

Output may look like:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [2], [3], [1], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` from `collections` to have a `dict` of `lists`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lists_dict = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(1,10):
   value = int(input("Score: "))
   lists_dict[f"list_{i}"].append(value)

print(dict(lists_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'list_1': [1], 'list_2': [2], 'list_3': [3], 'list_4': [4], 'list_5': [5], 'list_6': [6], 'list_7': [7], 'list_8': [8], 'list_9': [9]}
```